# How to simulate inference of intersection types

Tags: f#

lets say i have 2 interfaces

```
type Foo = abstract member Foo : Unit -> string
type Bar = abstract member Bar : Unit -> string
```

and 2 other interfaces that derive from them

```
type FooBar1 = 
    inherit Foo
    inherit Bar

type FooBar2 =
    abstract member Wibble : Unit -> string
    inherit Foo
    inherit Bar
```

I have a function that can take a choice of either of these 2 things

```
let g (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) =
```

and all it wants to do is call Foo and Bar, an unsafe example would be

```
let g (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) = 
    let xAsObject = 
        match x with 
        | Choice1Of2 foo1 -> 
            foo1 :> obj
        | Choice2Of2 foo2 ->
            foo2 
    
    let foo = (xAsObject :?> Foo).Foo()
    let bar = (xAsObject :?> Bar).Bar()
    (foo,bar)
```

ok, nasty casts....we can go like this:

```
let i y = 
    ((y :> Foo).Foo(),(y :> Bar).Bar())

let h (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) = 
    match x with 
    | Choice1Of2 foo1 -> 
        i foo1
    | Choice2Of2 foo2 ->
        i foo2
```

but if I have a few of these shared types, then it gets quite unwieldy all this explicit casting (though this is how i handle it now).

ideally I want to go like this:

```
let thisDoesntCompile (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) = 
    let xIntersection = 
        match x with 
        | Choice1Of2 foo1 -> 
            foo1
        | Choice2Of2 foo2 ->
            foo2

    let foo = xIntersection.Foo()
    let bar = xIntersection.Bar()
    (foo,bar)
```

but the compiler wont let me do that because it doesnt support intersection types, is there a nice way around this?

Really the ultimate aim is to do something like this, i.e. have a function that will take a function that can be applied to any member of the Choice, and apply it, but because of the above (which is effectively the same issue), I can't get to the below

```
let mapChoice f (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) = 
    match x with 
    | Choice1Of2 foo1 -> 
        f foo1
    | Choice2Of2 foo2 ->
        f foo2

let i y = 
    ((y :> Foo).Foo(),(y :> Bar).Bar())

let k (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) = 
    mapChoice i x
```

i.e. the object of the exercise is to able to apply any function to a choice that each choice individually could be passed. That logically is defined on the intersection of the types of the choices

---

i was going to delete this question because I think its been misinterpreted (so its a badly written question), but stackoverflow says I shouldnt do that. I may have another go, thanks to all those that have replied so far.

Comment: Would you be willing to define a `FooBar` interface that's a `Foo` and a `Bar`, and then inherit both `FooBar1` and `FooBar2` from `FooBar`?

Comment: well....actually in my use case the types are autogenerated by something i wrote, so yes I can do that in most cases...but its a pain.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand, why you want to cast in the first place. Unless you need the concrete object instance for something else, you can simply write:

```
type Foo =
    abstract member Foo : unit -> string
type Bar =
    abstract member Bar : unit -> string
type FooBar1 =
    inherit Foo
    inherit Bar

type FooBar2 =
    abstract member Wiggle : unit -> string
    inherit Foo
    inherit Bar

let g (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) =
    match x with
    | Choice1Of2 f1 ->
        (f1.Foo(),f1.Bar())
    | Choice2Of2 f2 ->
        (f2.Foo(),f2.Bar())
```

No casts, no bells, no whistles.

If you are flexible with the argument type of `g`, you could also use type constraints:

```
let inline h (x: ^T when ^T :> Foo and ^T :> Bar) =
    (x.Foo(),x.Bar())
```

Comment: yes, the point being that the Foo/Bar piece in your match is now repeated, if this logic is non trivial, then you basically have to implement the same function twice for 2 different types.

Comment: thats really what i did with the i/h example, but i factored the repeated logic out.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd I added another option you have to my answer - refresh the browser to see ;)

Comment: your last function h, is the SRTP version of the i function in the question, you've explicitly declared the type, ive (safe) cast, and the the compiler take the strain.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd Not to my understanding. Your cast happens at run time (like COM QueryInterface()), while this type constraint version happens at compile time.

Comment: "let i y = 
    ((y :> Foo).Foo(),(y :> Bar).Bar())" this isnt an unsafe cast.

Comment: Lets go back to the basics: Your function wants an `x`, which implements both `Foo` and `Bar`. You do not want duplicate code. The type constraint version does exactly that. What else do you want?

Comment: The end of the question shows some code that doesnt compile. Where you abstract the match so you can simply apply a function to a choice, intersection types would enable this, thats not to say it can't be done using parametric constraints, but thats whats missing

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @BitTickler that the problem seems artificial as presented. If you can't change the types and need concrete `Foo` and `Bar` values, you could also do this:

```ml
let thisDoesCompile (x: Choice<FooBar1,FooBar2>) = 
    let aFoo, aBar = 
        match x with
        | Choice1Of2 foo1 -> 
            foo1 :> Foo, foo1 :> Bar
        | Choice2Of2 foo2 ->
            foo2 :> Foo, foo2 :> Bar

    let foo = aFoo.Foo()
    let bar = aBar.Bar()
    (foo,bar)
```

Comment: Very nice, in an artificial way :)

Comment: yes, this is an example actually i didn't put in my question, mainly because I prefer the 'h' and 'i' function example.